# memory available to drush

Tags: drush

If one allocates additional memory to drush in drushrc.php or drush.ini (am I correct that these are potentially valid options on a shared server?), is there a way to confirm that this amount is actually allocated when running drush?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ drush ev 'print ini_get("memory_limit");'
```

This should print the memory_limit value set for Drush.  -1 means no limit.